# Convert "2.45" to decimal

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

I know this is the silliest question to ask. But really I'm having trouble to convert price(string) to decimal. Here is what I have tried

```
string s = "123.45";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

But I'm getting Format exception

Also tried

```
decimal num;
bool pass = decimal.TryParse("2.85", out num);
```

num comes out as 0.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to use ',' instead of '.' in case of delimiter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try specifying an invariant culture in which `.` is the decimal separator:

```
string s = "123.45";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(
    s, 
    NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

The `Parse` method uses the current thread culture to parse numbers. So if you are using some culture in which `.` is not the decimal separator (such as `fr-FR` for example) it won't work as it would expect the number to be `123,45` for instance.

Comment: REALLY REALLY sorry Darin!!! I saw your answer had appeared just before mine, and was already getting votes, and so I deleted my answer - or SO I THOUGHT! - I clicked the wrong button. I got it wrong. I error'd. My bad. Sorry again. I really wouldn't do that on purpose.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, no problem, happens to me all the time as well. My Google Chrome sometimes autoscrolls to the wrong answer and I edit other people's answers by mistake.

Comment: unfortunately I was bitten by the ♦ ability to instantly kill anything... oops.